# Stop update*Input from invalidating reactive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm looking for a way to stop `update*Input` functions from invalidating reactive values in my Shiny app. I want the update function to change only the visual UI component, not the underlying reactive value.

Here's a reprex:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sliderInput("slide1", "Slider", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
    sliderInput("slide2", "Slider2", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
    
    textOutput("slide2_val")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observe({
        updateSliderInput(session, "slide2", value = input$slide1)
    }) |> 
        bindEvent(input$slide1)
    
    output$slide2_val <- renderText({
        paste("Value of `slide2`:", input$slide2)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The desired behaviour is for the value of `input$slide2` to only change when the user interacts with slide2, but for the slider UI element to change when either slide1 or slide2 are interacted with.

Importantly, this needs to work for a variety of `input*` functions. Listening for click events won't work for inputs like `selectInput` (see my [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061061/on-click-for-shiny-inputs-to-get-last-input-clicked-doesnt-work-for-selectinput)).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2914) you can find a related GitHub issue.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, this doesn't work for me. See my comment on that issue.

Comment: You could use a `reactiveVal` and only update it on manual input.

Comment: The issue seems to be with how the JS code is working. If I add `print(input$slide2_manualchange)` inside an observer, it prints `TRUE` whenever it updates either programmatically or manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [recent answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438718/4550695)
I made a `suspendForNextFlush()` function to temporarily stop changes to an
input from being sent to Shiny. That function could be used to solve your
problem, too.

I’ve gone ahead and put the function in an experimental
[shinysuspend](https://github.com/mikmart/shinysuspend) package. You can
install it from GitHub with:

```r
remotes::install_github("mikmart/shinysuspend")
```

Then include `useShinysuspend()` in the UI, and call `suspendForNextFlush()`
when updating `slide2` from the server:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinysuspend)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinysuspend(),
  sliderInput("slide1", "Slider 1", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
  sliderInput("slide2", "Slider 2", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
  textOutput("slide2_val")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    suspendForNextFlush("slide2")
    updateSliderInput(session, "slide2", value = input$slide1)
  })
  
  output$slide2_val <- renderText({
    paste("Value of `slide2`:", input$slide2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```